# Calculate variance and standard deviation for Log Normal Distribution

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to calculate the variance and standard deviation for a log normal distribution.  I was able to calculate the mean after reading this stack exchange article [How to calculate a mean and standard deviation for a lognormal distribution using 2 percentiles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79281/how-to-calculate-a-mean-and-standard-deviation-for-a-lognormal-distribution-usin?rq=1).  Now I want to calculate the variance and standard deviation.  I am unclear what formulas I can use.  I will calculate this in R.

Comment: What are your data like? How much data do you have?

Comment: I have 205k rows of data that is cycle time data.

Comment: So are these durations (length of time until something happens)? Do you have any censoring?

Comment: Hello Gung, I am not sure what you mean by censoring.  My data is cycle time in days.  Does that help?

Comment: Do you have any observations where you don't know the exact cycle time, but only know that it was longer than $d$ days (eg it was still running when the data were collected)?

Comment: Hello Gung, thanks for staying with me on this.  No, I know the exact cycle time for all observations in the data set.

Comment: The calculation of variance and SD for a set of data does not depend on any other assumptions: use the standard formulas.  Do you perhaps want to *estimate* the variance under the assumption that your data are some kind of random sample from a lognormal distribution? Or are you looking for a way to compute the variance from some mathematical description, such as the PDF of a lognormal distribution?

Comment: Hello, I was hoping to just determine the center and spread of my data using mean and standard deviation.  Because the data is log-normal, I have taken the log of the data.  Once I have done that, the mean formula didn't provide an answer that seemed to make sense.  I found the stack exchange article noted in my question that helped me find the mean.  Now I was just trying to find a measure of spread for my logged data that I could be interpreted in the units of the original data (cycle time in days).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. An obvious choice even for estimating the population mean and variance would be to exponentiate your log-data back to original data and just directly calculate sample mean and sample variance (then you wouldn't have to rely on your assumption that the data are in fact lognormal, an assumption that's almost certainly false).
2. However, the assumption of lognormality might be close enough to true that it won't be so bad if you assume it anyway.

   In the case where the random variable is actually lognormal (with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$), the MLE of the $\mu$ parameter will be the sample mean of the logs, and the MLE of the $\sigma^2$ parameter will be $\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot s^2$, a simple rescaling of the sample variance of the logs.

   You could then produce estimates of the population mean ($m=\widehat{E(Y)}$), variance ($v=\widehat{\text{Var}(Y)}$) and hence of sd -

   $\text{estimated mean} = m = e^{\hat{\mu}+\frac12\hat{\sigma}^2}$

   $\text{estimated variance} = v = m^2 \cdot (e^{\hat{\sigma}^2}-1)$

   $\text{estimated s.d.} = \sqrt{v}$

   [However, $m$ and $v$ won't be unbiased. If unbiasedness of either is important to you, you may want to consider other possibilities, including the original suggestion.]

   Note that these are not the only possible estimators of those quantities under that lognormal assumption, but they're reasonably convenient if you must use the log-data.