# Convert median absolute deviation (MAD) to SD for log-normal distribution

Tags: standard-deviation, lognormal-distribution, mad

How do I convert the $\text{MAD}$ (median absolute deviation from the median) of data that is drawn from a log-normal distribution to the standard deviation of a log-normal distribution? To clarify, if I calculate the $\text{MAD}$ of a sample that I assume follows a log-normal distribution ($\text{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$), how do I calculate $\sigma$?

I know that such relationship exists for symmetrical distributions. E.g., for normal distribution that would be:

$\sigma=\Phi^{-1}(3/4)\cdot \text{MAD}\approx1.4826\cdot\text{MAD},$

where $\Phi()$ is the cumulative distribution function for the standard normal distribution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because medians are defined in terms of order only, they will be preserved under any order-preserving transformation of the variable.  So: take logarithms and apply what you know about the Normal distribution, then back-transform.

Comment: Would you please be able to walk me through the steps? Once I take the logarithms I can calculate the standard deviation of the normally distributed data, but how do I convert it back to the sd of the lognormal distribution?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173715/calculate-variance-and-standard-deviation-for-log-normal-distribution.  For more, search our site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+standard+deviation+formula.