# How calculate mean from 50th and 95th percentile?

Tags: r, standard-deviation, mean, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to calculate the mean from two values, the 50th and 95th percentiles of a log normal distribution using R. Those values are 0.3 for the 50th percentile and 9.1 for the 95th percentile.

Actually, I am trying to apply the method used in [How to calculate a mean and standard deviation for a lognormal distribution using 2 percentiles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79281/how-to-calculate-a-mean-and-standard-deviation-for-a-lognormal-distribution-usin?rq=1), but I don't understand how the mean can be calculated with that mean = mean(ln((42 \ 666))). I don't understand that sign . I tried with this sign / but the results were different.

How to determinate the mean those two percentiles by using R ?

Comment: The code you're looking at is not R code.

Comment: the corresponding R code would be mean <- mean(log(c(42, 666)))